# Why spacing is not equal in collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, cell, spacing, collectionview

The collectionView shows cells without any problem except the spacing, some spacing are not equal to others, they are a little bit bigger than others. Even I set `margin = 0`, some spacing still comes out.

Here is the code:

```
let margin = 1
let cellSize = (size.width-margin*(cellsPerRow+1)) / cellsPerRow
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: margin, left: margin, bottom: margin, right: margin)
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellSize, height: cellSize)
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = margin
layout.minimumLineSpacing = margin
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You are performing a division: `let cellSize = (size.width-margin*(cellsPerRow+1)) / cellsPerRow`. What should happen if the division doesn't go evenly? You can't have a nonintegral number of points.

Comment: I looks like your arithmetic is wrong, you need to adjust you brackets. 
let cellSize = ((size.width-margin)*(cellsPerRow+1)) / cellsPerRow

Comment: @matt cellsPerRow is converted to CGFloat before operation.

Comment: @arvidurs it's totally wrong size ;-(

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the cell size based on maximum (integer) width/height that fits your whole area, then take the "leftover" (=area_width_or_height - (cell_size*cell_amount) ) and divide it by two to get the size of margins you need to leave to left/right/top/bottom to make the grid even. Now you get your cells slightly random based on whether you round to lower or higher number.